# How to fix "TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" in python regression

Tags: python-2.7, optimization, scipy, least-squares

I tried to use scipy.optimize package for regression. The model of the function is defined in func with parameters named as coeffs. I want to use the data xdata and ydata to learn the parameters using LS criterion.

I have the following TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

```py
from __future__ import division
import numpy
import scipy
from math import exp
import scipy.optimize as optimization

global m0,t0

t0 = 0.25
m0=1
def func(t, coeffs):
    a = coeffs[0]
    b = coeffs[1]
    m = (a/b + m0 )*exp(b*(t-t0))-a/b
    return m

# fitting test
x0 = numpy.array([5, -5], dtype=float)

def residuals(coeffs, y, t):
    return y - func(t, coeffs)

xdata = numpy.array([0.25,0.5,1])
ydata = numpy.array([1.0,0.803265329856,0.611565080074])

from scipy.optimize import leastsq
x = leastsq(residuals, x0, args=(ydata, xdata))
```

return parameters are expected around [2,-1].

Comment: Your `math.exp` requires a scalar.  Is there something in your code, say the 2 element `x0` that makes its argument an array? Or the `b`?  `np.exp` accepts an array argument.

Comment: Ultimiately `t` will be assigned `xdata`, so the `exp` function must be changed to `np.exp` to allow element-wise evaluation of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `from math import exp`, replace it by `from numpy import exp` so that your arrays are correctly handled: the `numpy.exp` function will return the array expected by scipy, with each element converted to its exponential value.